# Angular 2/5: backup ngrx state

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ngrx

I am trying to build a mechanism to store current app state (built with `ngrx`) on the backend. I could monitor root app state changes subscribing to the store and perform a request on each change with such simple code:

```
// some service declaration

constructor(private _store: Store<AppState>) {
    this.store.subscribe(
        state => makeHttpRequestToBackupStateOnBackendSide(state);
    );
}

// further service logics
```

but this is definitely a bad idea which will result in http request hell (though could be slightly improved with debouncing the stream).

I also thought to backup it once on `app.component` `ngOnDestroy` hook, but it also seems unsuitable.

So, for now I think of two approaches achieving this and none of them seems 100% suitable:

1. `app.component` `ngOnDestroy` hook
2. subscribing to the app state with a debounce: this will cut the request amount, but may bring other downsides

Please share your experience implementing this.

Comment: How about using ngrx/effects, and saving based on any of the actions that would require saving?

Comment: this sounds reasonable, though not perfect, I assume... as it means "mirroring" each single request which fetches new data with a backup call, but for sure I need to think this way too